# Running Ansible playbooks in Jenkins fails decryption

Tags: jenkins, ansible, ansible-vault

On my development machine everything works great. It's just that when Jenkins attempts to run playbooks that are associated with vault-encrypted files, I see the error:

```
ERROR! Decryption failed on /data/jenkins/workspace/.../secrets.yml 
FATAL: command execution failed hudson.AbortException: Ansible playbook execution failed
```

The command that was executed from the Jenkins job is:

```
/usr/bin/ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i prod/inventory -l localhost -s -f 1 --vault-password-file /etc/ansible/vault_password
```

The vault password file is confirmed to exist at the location with the following permissions:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 35 Dec 18 13:23 /etc/ansible/vault_password
```

If I run the same command but ask for password (interactively), everything runs okay. This is however not the desired workflow: I'd like Jenkins to run these playbooks all on its own, without user interaction.

I should mention that the playbook is meant to run tasks locally, essentially to prepare the environment for Maven testing (creating expected resources such as properties files).

Comment: what is the user which jenkins is running?

Comment: That would be my username on Mac OSX (which succeeds), and "jenkins" on the CentOS machines where Jenkins is running the playbook. The "jenkins" user is in sudoers.d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there is a huge difference between creating a file with content and copying a file with content, even if the end result is a file with the same content.

Let me explain: my provisioning playbook had been creating my password file by writing the password to a file on the remote machines, like this:

```
copy: content="{{ ansibl_vault_password }}", dest="{{ ansibl_vault_password_file }}"
```

The change I made was for the password file to be copied from my machine to the remote machines, like this:

```
  copy:
    src: "{{ ansibl_vault_password_file }}"
    dest: "{{ ansibl_vault_password_file }}"
    mode: "u=rw,g=r,o=r"
```

So even if in the grand scheme of things I ended up with a file containing the password on the first line, the earlier approach kept failing to decrypt contents whereas the second approach worked just fine.